# Slow memory leak, how to find?

Tags: ram, memory-leak

We have a miniPC running Ubuntu Studio 22.04 which handles the processing of the audio for our FM broadcast transmitter. It is meant to operate 24/7/365 with little to no administration.

Over time I am seeing a slow memory leak, ~300Mb / day, like this:

```
as of 10/17/2023
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            12Gi       3.1Gi       7.4Gi       160Mi       2.1Gi       9.0Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
Total:          12Gi       3.1Gi       7.4Gi
```

and

```
as of 10/19/2023
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            12Gi       3.8Gi       529Mi       155Mi       8.2Gi       8.2Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
Total:          12Gi       3.8Gi       529Mi
```

Whatever is chewing away at memory is pretty far down in top, so I'd like to find a bit of script that can take a snapshot of maybe the top 40 processes and compare memory usage of each process day-over-day to find the culprit. How can I do that? Thank you.